# Adding geometry to a db table using ArcPy from an existing points dataset

Tags: arcpy, cursor, file-geodatabase, field-mapping

I am attempting to write an ArcPy script to add the geometries of a points data set to records in a db table. Each record in the db table has a field containing a date, and an associated numeric value (in this case 2 or 5). The points dataset contains a start date and an associated numeric value.

What I need to do is either add the geometry from the points dataset to the db table, making it a point feature class, or copy the records from the db table into the associated points record with the appropiate geometry. To figure out which geometry is appropriate, the date in the db table has to be greater than or equal to the date in the points feature class, but less than the next date in the points feature class when viewed chronologicly.

I have tried maybe a dozen different scripts, and I can't get anything to work. I also haven't been able to find much online.

Below is what I have been attempting, but I can't get it to properly add a field and copy the lat and long of the points into their own fields. I plan to use the Display XY tool to convert the table into a feature class.

```
import arcpy

# Set the input parameters
points_fc = r"C:/Users/devin/OneDrive - University of Denver/Denver GIS/Capstone Doc/Pro Project/Capstone/Capstone.gdb/Merge"
db_table = r"C:/Users/devin/OneDrive - University of Denver/Denver GIS/Capstone Doc/Pro Project/Capstone/Capstone.gdb/db_table"

# Add the new fields to store the lat and long in the db table
arcpy.AddField_management(db_table, "lat", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(db_table, "long", "DOUBLE")

# Add the lat and long fields to the points feature class
arcpy.management.AddXY(points_fc)

# Create a search cursor to iterate through the db table records
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(db_table, ["OID@", "Detector", "Date"]) as db_cursor:
    # For each record in the db table, find the corresponding point in the points feature class
    for db_row in db_cursor:
        oid = db_row[0]
        detector = db_row[1]
        date = db_row[2]
        lat = None
        long = None
        
        # Create a cursor to iterate through the points feature class
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points_fc, ["OID@", "Detector", "Date", "POINT_X", "POINT_Y"]) as points_cursor:
            for point_row in points_cursor:
                # Check if the detector and date fields match the values in the db table record
                if point_row[1] == detector and point_row[2] >= date:
                    # Check if there are more points in the cursor
                    try:
                        next_point = next(points_cursor)
                    except StopIteration:
                        next_point = None
                    
                    if next_point is None or next_point[2] > date:
                        # Get the lat and long of the point
                        lat = point_row[3]
                        long = point_row[4]
                        break
        
        # Update the db table record with the lat and long values
        if lat is not None and long is not None:
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(db_table, ["lat", "long"]) as update_cursor:
                for update_row in update_cursor:
                    if update_row[0] == oid:
                        update_cursor.updateRow((lat, long))
                        break

# Print a message to indicate that the script has completed
print("Finished updating lat and long values in db table")
```

Comment: Looking at [Add Field (Data Management)- ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm), Geometry is not one of the supported data types so the first approach won't work.

Comment: Never iterate a SearchCursor inside a SearchCursor, much less a SearchCursor *and* an UpdateCursor. You can execute a ALTER TABLE in an ArcSDESQLExecute cursor, but not while an other cursor is open.

Comment: I understand that I shouldn't be using nested cursors, but this is thus far the only way I could find for it to not throw errors. It doesn't actually copy the lat long into the table tho. I am not familiar with that method and am trying to keep it solely in Arcpy if possible as this is for a project for a small non-profit with no GIS staff, and limited understanding amongst the rest of staff

Comment: Are these file geodatabases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer over the weekend. It likely could be improved upon, but it executed what I needed it too slightly differently than I had envisioned. It coppies the lat and long into the table instead of assigning geometries, but with the Display XY tool, this gets the job done.

```
import arcpy

# Set the input parameters
fc = r"C:/Users/devin/OneDrive - University of Denver/Denver GIS/Capstone Doc/Pro Project/Capstone/Capstone.gdb/Merge"
table = r"C:/Users/devin/OneDrive - University of Denver/Denver GIS/Capstone Doc/Pro Project/Capstone/Capstone.gdb/db_table"


# Add the lat and long fields to the db table
arcpy.management.AddField(table, "lat", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.management.AddField(table, "long", "DOUBLE")

# Create an empty dictionary to store the key-value pairs
point_dict = {}

# Use the SearchCursor function to iterate through the rows of the feature class and create the dictionary
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["Date", "Shape@XY", "Detector"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        date = row[0]
        lat = row[1][1]
        long = row[1][0]
        detector = row[2]
        point_dict[date] = (lat, long, detector)

# Sort the dates in the dictionary in chronological order
sorted_dates = sorted(point_dict.keys())

# Create Search Cursor to iterate through rows in the table
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, ["Date", "lat", "long", "Detector"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Get the date and detector value for the current row
        date = row[0]
        t_detector = row[3]
        if date < sorted_dates[0]:
            # Assign the latitude and longitude values of the earliest date in the sorted_dates list to the current row
            lat, long, detector = point_dict[sorted_dates[0]]
            row[1] = lat
            row[2] = long
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            # Iterate through the sorted dates in the dictionary
            for i in range(len(sorted_dates) - 1):
                lat, long, detector = point_dict[sorted_dates[i]]
                # Checks the values in the table and dictionary to ensure they match before updating the lat and long
                if date >= sorted_dates[i] and t_detector == detector:
                    if i < len(sorted_dates) - 1 and date < sorted_dates[i + 1]:
                        row[1] = lat
                        row[2] = long
                        cursor.updateRow(row)
                    else:
                        row[1] = lat
                        row[2] = long
                        cursor.updateRow(row)
```